# Once in a month I get this Azure alert message "The db DTU utilization is 0 for the last 1 hour "

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have Hangfire job in my project which copies data from source A to B. My application is hosted in Azure and I use Azure SQL Database. every month I get this alert message from Azure portal "The db DTU utilization is 0 for the last 1 hour". Unable to get the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

**DTU stands for Database Transaction Unit. DTUs give you a way to compare database performance across the service tiers offered by Azure. DTUs roughly measure performance as a combination of CPU, Memory, Reads, and Writes.**

So, the alert message "The db DTU utilization is 0 for the last 1 hour " means the database is not in use and there is no read/write or I/O operation is happening on your database, therefore no DTU is in use for that period of time.

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-Mt,

Thank you for your explanation it's really useful. But whenever this issue come we need to clear the Queued Hangfire jobs. Restart the App service which has hangfire jobs and rerun the jobs manually.